# How to close Python socket server when all of its multiple clients close the connection?

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets

I have made a multithreaded Python socket server.

It supports multiple socket client connections.

My code is:

```
import socket
from _thread import *

def multi_threaded_client(connection):
    response = ''
    while True:
        data = connection.recv(10000000)
        response += data.decode('utf-8')
        if not data:
            print(response)
            break
        connection.send(bytes(some_function_name(response), "utf-8"))
    connection.close()



class socketserver:
    def __init__(self, address='', port=9090):
        self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.address = address
        self.port = port
        self.sock.bind((self.address, self.port))
        self.cummdata = ''

    def recvmsg(self):
        self.sock.listen(65535)
        self.conn, self.addr = self.sock.accept()
        print('connected to', self.addr)
        self.cummdata = ''
        
        start_new_thread(multi_threaded_client, (self.conn, ))

        return self.cummdata
        
    def __del__(self):
        self.sock.close()

serv = socketserver('127.0.0.1', 9090)

print('Socket Created at {}. Waiting for client..'.format(serv.sock.getsockname()))

while True:
    msg = serv.recvmsg()
```

I also want the server to detect if any new client is connected to /disconnected from it.

Once all the clients are disconnected from it, I want the server to be closed on its own.

I could not figure this out

Comment: So only one client will be able to use the system? doesn't make much sense. If the server stops listening after the first client disconnects, only 1 client will ever be able to use the system

Comment: You might want to use the standard library SocketServer instead of rolling your own stuff. Also, your socket reading code won't properly read messages that may be transmitted over multiple packets.

Comment: Also, can you explain what your app should do in the grand scale? Right now I'm seeing it receives some data, calls a function and sends some data back to the client.

Comment: @DeepSpace More than 1 clients were able to connect to my socket server one at a time. Suppose there are N socket clients 1,2,3,4,....N connected to this server. Currently, when these N clients are connected, if I close any client's connection, the socket server keeps running as expected. Now the point is that if I close the connection for all the clients, in that case I want to close the server.

Comment: @AKX It is some Artifical Intelligence based Prediction socket server in Python

Comment: @test I'd recommend making it a regular HTTP server if you don't need multiple request/responses per connection, or a websocket server if you do. Otherwise you'll have to roll your own encapsulation and so on.

Comment: @AKX There would be only 1 request from a connection at a time.So, total N requests at a time from N clients. Would the async package resolve this? I basically want a counter which is initially 0 & increments for any new connection. Once all the connections are removed, socket server should close when the counter is 0 (Just guessing!)

Comment: You're still using raw TCP connections in a way that won't work in the long run (e.g. longer messages) without additional encapsulation...